# Creating domains and loading assemblies in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix

This is kind of complicated, but I will try to make it as clear as possible. I am creating a visual studio extension that has a menu item added to the context menu when you right click a project (and the project matches certain criteria). The menu is supposed to trigger a process that will:

1) Build the project

2) Create a new AppDomain

3) Load the new assembly into the new AppDomain

4) Return some object from the new AppDomain that is defined in a third assembly (i.e. not the extension assembly or the built project) but is referenced by *both* the other two.

The problem I keep constantly running into is with number 4 and convincing the extension that the type from the third assembly (let's call it `foo.dll` and the type `FooAssembly`) is the same type.

In my extension (let's call that `extension.dll`) I have this:

```
// assemblyPath is the path to the dll I just build for the selected project
var setup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
    ApplicationBase = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath)
};

domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test_AppDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

// FooAssembly is defined in foo.dll and is reference by *both* the project.dll and
// but the extension.dll it exists both in the assemblyPath folder
// and typeof(FooAssembly).Assembly.Location which is NOT the same as
// the current AppDomain's CodeBase because the current CodeBase is the
// CodeBase of Visual Studio in this context
var obj = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    typeof(FooAssembly).Assembly.FullName,
    typeof(FooAssembly).FullName,
    false,
    BindingFlags.Default,
    null,
    new object[] { assemblyPath, typeof(FooAssembly).Assembly.Location }, null, null);

// This says the type is MarshalByRefObject
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(obj.GetType().Name);

// this sets collection to null because it can't cast it
// which is essentially my problem
collection = obj as FooAssembly;
```

Now my `FooAssembly`, defined in `foo.dll` and referenced by both `extension.dll` and `project.dll` looks like this:

```
public class FooAssembly: MarshalByRefObject
{
    private Assembly _assembly;

    public FooAssembly(string assemblyPath, string parentPath)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (o, e) =>
        {
            // this event never seems to get fired
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"attempt to resolve {e.Name} for {e.RequestingAssembly.FullName}");
            return null;
        };
        // this didn't seem to help
        //Assembly.LoadFrom(parentPath);      // load spider assembly from same place (hopefully)...
        // I've tried LoadFrom as well, with the same result
        _assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
    }

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So what is actually going on here and how can I make it behave itself? I need the AppDomain I created to load the assembly I give it, and then load it's dependencies (or at least `foo.dll`) from the same location that the extension gets it from, I think. Or at the very least I need it to know that my transparent proxy *is* `FooAssembly`.

**EDIT**: I tried copying my `project.dll` into the same folder as `extension.dll` so that it would have to load from the same location. This didn't make any difference, so I tried sticking these line into my `FooAssembly` constructor:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().FullName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase);
```

And I can see that a) I'm in the created domain. b) I have the right class and c) I appear to have the right path?!? The `CodeBase` comes back as:

`file:///C:/USERS/MATT.BURLAND/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0EXP/EXTENSIONS/SOMECO/FOOTOOLS/1.0/Foo.DLL`

So in my default domain after creating the domain and before trying to create an object, I do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(SpiderAssembly).FullName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(SpiderAssembly).Assembly.CodeBase);
```

And here my code base is:

`file:///C:/USERS/MATT.BURLAND/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/14.0EXP/EXTENSIONS/SOMECO/FOOTOOLS/1.0/foo.dll`

The only difference here being the casing on `foo.dll` vs `Foo.DLL`, which I believe shouldn't be significant.

I tried this (inspired by [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Jan/13/Unable-to-cast-transparent-proxy-to-type-type)):

```
dynamic dobj = obj;
string l2 = dobj.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(l2);
```

And it clearly thinks it's a `MarshalByRefObject` loaded from `file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll`, so it seems like it's not unwrapping correctly?

**Edit:** After reading more around this, I have a theory. For the `foo.dll` to be shared between domains it has to be loaded "domain-neutral" and my current theory is that my extension is probably isolated in it's own domain by visual studio and so `foo.dll` is loaded by more code in a way that is *not* domain neutral which means the app domain I create has to load it's own copy. Does that make any sense? Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching around and multiple attempt to rearrange code, I eventually cracked this when I found the [ProvideBindingPathAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providebindingpathattribute(v=vs.120).aspx).

I added `[ProvideBindingPath]` to my package class and the problems that had been plaguing me went away. I no longer needed to mess around with the `ApplicationBase` for my domain and could just pass `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation` for the `AppDomainSetup` for my new `AppDomain`.